# what does filepath.Base do in golang

Tags: go

I am looking at this snippet of code:

```
if len(os.Args) == 1 {
        fmt.Printf("usage: %s <whole-number>\n", filepath.Base(os.Args[0]))
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

I understand what it does. `os.Args` is the list of the arguments. The program is supposed to be invoked from the command line, so it checks to see if the arguments given exceeds 1 (The first one being `os.Args[0]` is the program's name itself) and if it doesn't, it exits the program and prints an informative error.

However I don't really get this part `filepath.Base(os.Args[0])`. `filepath.Base` returns the base of a filepath (namely, its file name). But doesn't `os.Args[0]` already contain the name? So what this extra step does and why is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`filepath.Base`](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Base) returns the last path element of the provided string. `os.Args[0]` may be a single binary's name, a relative path, or a fully qualified path. This is simply a way to normalize that.